# Conditionally Loop Through and Execute Stored Procedures in SQL Table

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I currently have a SQL Server table consisting of a number of stored procedures, each stored procedure belongs to a parent chapter. For example:

Stored procedures with IDs 1001-1199 belong to Chapter 1
Stored procedures with IDs 1200-1299 belong to Chapter 2
Stored procedures with IDs 1300-1399 belong to Chapter 3
etc...

Within context of SSIS I have created an ADO ForEachLoop container for each chapter and its stored procedures (8 chapter containers total). As of right now the intention is each chapter's loop will access an object variable containing the entire table and loop through each stored procedure that corresponds to that chapter, then execute it with an Execute SQL Task. What I am trying to do is figure out a simple way of selecting a given chapter's stored procedures conditionally from the object variable and executing them before moving on to the next chapter.

So, for example, Chapter 1's loop would select just stored procedures 1001-1199 from the table in the object variable and execute them, then proceed to the next chapter loop.

The idea of using the expressions on the precedent constraints between chapters occurred to me, but if I can apply a condition/expression to the collection of stored procedures by the loop container itself, that would seem ideal.

I am somewhat new to SSIS and SQL Server, and would appreciate any solution recommendations along with an explanation for my understanding. Please and thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume you already have variables for the `ProcID` and `ProcName` mapped in the existing `ForEachLoop` `VariableMappings`.  The only remaining task to filter on `ProcID` within each loop  so that only the stored procedures associated with the context chapter are processed.  This can be done as follows.

1) Add an empty `Sequence Container` to each of your `ForEachLoop` containers

2) Link each new `Sequence Container` with a `Precedence Constraint` to the first (or only) task in each `ForEachLoop` container

3) Edit each `Precedence Constraint` before the first task to specify the following properties:

```
Evaluate Operation: Expression
Expression (different for each chapter): @[User::ProcID] >= 1001 && @[User::ProcID] <= 1199
```

Below is an example of the package control flow after these changes:

[image: Package control flow after changes]

If each chapter ForEach loop is identical except for the stored procs executed, consider refactoring to use nested ForEach loops (i.e. ForEach Chapter and ForEach ChapterStoredProcedure). The first task of the ForEach Chapter container would load the collection of procs for the context chapter and then execute the ForEach ChapterStoredProcedure container.  No precedence constraint before the inner ForEach ChapterStoredProcedure is needed with this approach since the enumerator will contain only the procs for the current chapter.  Below is an example of this technique.

[image: Nested ForEach container example]

Comment: Your assumption was and is correct with the variable mappings. Thank you Dan, I configured and just tested with the first solution, successfully. That is a nice little trick with the empty Sequence Container within the ForEachLoop. For my current requirements and at least initially, I will be isolating each chapter, but the second solution with the nested loop is very elegant and simple. I appreciate your quick and detailed response, when I have the ability to "Vote-Up", I will do so. Please know your answer was a verified solution though.